# How can I implement SQLite database and FMDB into app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, uitableview

I have a SQLite database that I want my app to read and load into a UITableView then push to a Detail View.

I am using the FMDB wrapper framework (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).  I'm confused as to how exactly to do this as I've never used SQLite in an iPhone app before.

Can anyone help get me started?  What code do I need to add to I'm assuming viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use CoreData framework provided in iPhone SDK. Its pretty simple to use and it manages most of the complex things for us. It provides a way to use Sqlite database as a persistent store for your application. You can just start with it from the documentation provided in iPhone SDK documentation under "Core Data Programming guide" section.